# Can a delayed client request be on safe?

Tags: security

We are analyzing a financial web based application.

There are some security mechanism implemented in this application.

One of them prevents a request which take long time when traveling from server to client.

```
//Consider that client and server clocks are sync

If ( ( the server receiving time - the client sends time ) > 5 seconds )
{
   //Do not accept this request, it took so long !

}
```

I could not figure out why logic could be important. May be, if it took too long when a request is sent from client to server, means some middle application process or changes the request before sending it to actual server !!

I reviewed some parts of www.owasp.org but could not find any recommendation about this.

Do yo think this logic is valid?!

Comment: If the data is signed, this could be a bad mean to prevent a replay attack. If it is not signed, it doesn’t make any sense, except if it is used to implement the requirement that the clocks are synchronized.

Comment: @JonasWielicki the application is server on SSL so do you think this attack can happen in SSL connections too?!

Comment: depends. Is the SSL used to fully authenticate the client and the transaction?

Comment: @JonasWielicki, if you mean are all my connections ( log in + site internal pages) are SSL, Yes they are !

Answer (score 0):

If a man in the middle attack is done they can change the client send time, so this does not make sense in this small context.

Also it is quite common that computers are not synchronized with a time server. So to give a good answer more information is needed.